# How do I stub sqlmock to never return error?

Tags: sql, database, testing, go, mocking

I can not test the function `NewDao` that uses a database arbitrarily. I want to check whether the returned Dao have neither nil client nor nil product.

```golang
type Dao struct {
  client ClientDao
  product ProductDao
}

func (d *Dao) Client() ClientDao {
  return d.client
}

func (d *Dao) Product() ProductDao {
  return d.product
}

func NewDao(db *sql.DB) (*Dao, error) {
  if db == nil {
    return nil, errors.New("Can't create a dao from nil database")
  }
  client, err := newClientDao(db) // Uses db arbitrarily
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  product, err := newProductDao(db) // Uses db arbitrarily
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return &Dao{client, product}, nil
}
```

I test `NewDao()` using sqlmock but it always fails because I don't know what the mock needs to expect.

```golang
func TestNewDao(t *testing.T) {
  db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
  if err != nil {
    t.Fatal("Can't create database for test dao")
  }

  // How to set mock to expect anything and never fail?
  // mock.ExpectQuery(any) ?

  dao, err := NewDao(db)

  // err is never nil, because mock has no expectations

  if err != nil {
    t.Fatal("Can't create dao for test dao.User %q", err)
  }
  if dao.User() == nil {
    t.Fatalf("User dao is nil")
  }
  if dao.Client() == nil {
    t.Fatalf("Client dao is nil")
  }
}
```

---

Does any one know how to stub the sqlmock for achieving my purpose? Or can appoint an alternative to sqlmock lib?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the second item in your last return in `NewDao`:

`return &Dao{client, product}`

should be:

`return &Dao{client, product}, nil`

Return statements have to "return" all the things declared in the function header.

Comment: What I want is to figure out a way to make the test not depending on UserDao implementation, which uses db arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dao.Client` and `Dao.Product` methods themselves make no calls to any dependency and because of that there is nothing for you to mock. There is no point in using a mock for testing these two methods.

And although testing one liners like these may not be the most sensible thing to do, if you want to test them anyway you just need to make sure that the value they return equals the value of the field that they're supposed to return.

```
func TestDaoClient(t *testing.T) {
    var client ClientDao // TODO: prepare a client dao value for test

    tests := []struct{
        name string
        dao *Dao
        want ClientDao
    }{{
        name: "should return client dao",
        dao: &Dao{client: client},
        want: client,
    }, {
        name: "should return nil",
        dao: &Dao{client: nil},
        want: nil,
    }}

    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := tt.dao.Client(); !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tt.want) {
                t.Errorf("client got=%v, want=%v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })    
    }
}
```

Now you can do the same for the `Dao.Product` method.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I need not to use newClientDao(db) function to create the client to make this test. I put a bad example for my question.